# Would asking “How do you say cream of the crop In French” be a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Someone was asking on the English language site, what is meant by “[cream of the crop?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41325/cream-of-the-crop)”
.
An answerer speculated, that the origin might be French.

If I asked, “How do you say ‘cream of the crop’?” in French on this site, would that be considered a "duplicate" question?
Of course, the answer would be in French, which might make it a non-duplicate.
And while I “suspect” the origin might be French, I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange doesn't have a concept of cross-site duplicates.

Posting the exact same question on two Stack Exchange sites is [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073). But between [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and [French SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/), it wouldn't be the same question — there'd be one question about English and one about French. In this instance, asking about the origin of “cream of the crop” in English wouldn't be on-topic for French SE; asking about the origin and usage of “*crème de la crème*” in French would be.

If two questions are related, it would be a good idea to link to the existing question in your new question, regardless of whether the two questions are on the same site.

Answer (score 3):

The questions as they stand now on both sites makes perfect sense on each site, so I don't see any problem. They aren't exactly the same anyway. If it were an exact duplicate, I would expect that it actually be ill-formed on one of the sites, where it could be closed (or migrated).

Links from each of the questions to the other should definitely be present as they may give extra insight to the asker. Maybe stricly redundant part could be edited out if links are properly placed, but I don't even see any real necessity for that; quite the contrary: when linking to an external reference (such as wikipedia), it is usually recommended to cite the relevant part as well - so basically we would do the same when citing another SE site as reference.